# Guess from where a process is being called [Raspbian]

Tags: process, raspberry-pi

I have a java application running on boot in my Raspberry Pi and it's working fine. But I've noticed that after booting there are 2 processes of the same application, as if it was being called twice.

One is called from /etc/rc.local and the other I don't know from where, but I'd like to know it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the parent PID of a process (the calling process)

```
  cat /proc/1111/status | grep PPid
```

replace the '*1111*' with the PID of your process

See https://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

If I do ps -ef I can list all the processes running on my Pi. Second column is PID and third is PPID which is enough for me.